# AWK for data smoothing

Tags: awk

I need some help to smooth some data with awk olny of column 4 and next.
This is a data example:

```
Date;time;Time_ms;A;B;C;D
23.11.2012;15:03:00;41236627696;1;2;2;3
23.11.2012;15:04:00;41236628391;2;3;3;11
23.11.2012;15:06:00;41236629097;1;23;7;15
24.11.2012;15:07:00;41236627696;1;4;5;3
24.11.2012;15:08:00;41236628391;3;12;1;2
24.11.2012;15:09:00;41236629097;2;23;71;15;8
23.11.2012;15:10:00;41236627696;7;1;2;2;3
23.11.2012;15:11:00;41236628391;2;3;12;1;
23.11.2012;15:12:00;41236629097;22;2;7;15
```

The output should not modify  Date;time;Time_ms and print the average of A with the  A field of n row before and the A field of n row after. The same should be done for the  B, C, D... column.
For example if n=1 the second row will be:

```
23.11.2012;15:04:00;41236628391;(1+2+1)/3;(2+3+23)/3;(2+3+7)/3;(3+11+15)/3
```

Maybe something like this can be a startpoint

```
BEGIN { WIDTH=3 }

{       DATA[(++N)%WIDTH]=$0    }

(N>=WIDTH) {
        V=0
        for(X=(N+1); X<=(N+WIDTH); X++)
                V+=DATA[X%WIDTH];

        print V/WIDTH;
}
```

[Source](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/176427-smoothing-data.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the script that I wrote after that I found [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/193361-delimited-file-2d-array.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash     
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";"
    RS="\n"}
    {
           gsub(/\n/,"",$0) 
           if (max_nf<NF) 
               max_nf=NF 
           max_nr=NR 
           for(x=1; x<=NF; ++x) 
               vector[NR,x]=$x 
        } 
    END { 
    row=1
        printf vector[row,1] OFS vector[row,2] OFS vector[row,3]
               for(col=4; col<max_nf; ++col) 
                      printf OFS "Average(" vector[row,col] ")";
              printf ORS      

    for(row=2; row<max_nr; ++row) {
        printf vector[row,1] OFS vector[row,2] OFS vector[row,3]
              for(col=4; col<max_nf; ++col) 
                printf OFS (vector[row,col]+vector[row-1,col]+vector[row+1,col])/3 ;
            printf ORS
           } 
        }' File_IN.csv>File_OUT.csv
```

This script store the csv file a two dimensional array, then print the first line. For the column >4 print average(HEADER).
From the second row to the end of file print the first, the second and the third column and the average of column >4.
Even if the python script of @gilles works fine I chose this script as answer because uses AWK as asked.

Answer (score 3):

For statistical data processing, [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) is usually easier to use.

It is easier to read all the data into memory. Awk isn't the greatest language for that (though it is certainly possible). Here's a quickie Python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])     # the smooth parameter n must be passed as the first argument to the script
print sys.stdin.readline()  # print the header line
def split_line(line):  # split line into first 3 fields as string, then list of numbers
    fields = line[:-1].split(";")
    return [";".join(fields[:3])] + map(float, fields[3:7])
rows = map(split_line, sys.stdin.readlines())
def avg(i, j):
    return (rows[i-n][j] + rows[i][j] + rows[i+n][j]) / 3
for i in xrange(n, len(rows) - n):
    print ";".join([rows[i][0]] + [str(avg(i, j-2)) for j in xrange(3, 7)])
```

If your data is really huge, here's a script that I think does what you're asking. It reads 2*n+1 lines, stores the values in `prev[2*n]` through `prev[1]` plus `$0`, then prints the average for the (n+1)th line.

```
awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' -v n="${1-1}" '
    function avg(i) { return (prev[2*n, i] + prev[n, i] + $i) / 3; }
    NR == 1 { print; next }         # title line: print and skip the rest
    NR >= 2*n+2 {
        # fourth line on: print the average values from the past 3 lines
        # with the labels from the previous line
        print labels[n], avg(4), avg(5), avg(6), avg(7);
    }
    {
        # shift the saved averages by 1 position
        for (i=4; i<=7; i++) {
            for (k=2*n; k>1; k--) prev[k, i] = prev[k-1, i];
            prev[1, i] = $i;
        }
        # save the labels of this line to print in the next round
        for (k=n; k>1; k--) labels[k] = labels[k-1];
        labels[1] = $1 ";" $2 ";" $3;
    }
'
```

Comment: Bonjour @Gilles, I tried you awk script but as reslult I obtain a file that is the copy of the original... no vaerage is made. No errors are showed on terminal. I changed only these two things : FS=OFS=";"     RS="\r\n" . Have you tried the script? Is working well with you?

Comment: @Ludovico Sorry, I made some tweaks in my browser after I'd tested the code. Here are working versions.

Comment: I tried your script in python... Works fine!! Thank you!!! Works fine on the example but fails if there is a different number of column in the input. My input files doesn't have always the same number of column. How Can I calculate the number of culumn and execute the average on column from 4 to last column? The script fails also if one field is empty; Is it possible to consider empty fields as 0? The script in AWK don't work, but maybe I made some mistake... I'll verify